# Loop regression and save residuals in column

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I have a repeated cross-sections data file and I want to run OLS regression over the years in a loop and then save the residuals in a new column.

My data looks like:

```
Y      X   Year 
150    10  2005
120    11  2005
200    11  2006
180    15  2006
310    12  2007
280    09  2007
```

The equivalent function in Stata is:

```
forvalues i = 2005(1)2007{ 
qui reg Y X if year==`i' 
predict res`i' if year==`i', r
}
```

In summary, I need to transform the code above from Stata to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always provide sample data by creating some or using `dput()`. Here's a base R approach to your problem. First the data:

```
set.seed(42)
Year <- sample(2005:2007, 100, replace=TRUE)
Y <- sample(8:18, 100, replace=TRUE)
X <- sample(8:18, 100, replace=TRUE)
dat <- data.frame(Y, X, Year)
```

Now the analysis:

```
dat.spt <- split(dat, dat$Year)
res.spt <- lapply(dat.spt, function(k) residuals(lm(Y~X, k)))
dat.res <- data.frame(unsplit(dat.spt, Year), res=unsplit(res.spt, Year))
    head(dat.res)
#    Y  X Year        res
# 1 15 16 2005  0.7597518
# 2 14 13 2005  0.8477988
# 3 13 15 2005 -0.8775658
# 4  8  8 2005 -3.3387895
# 5 12 13 2006 -0.0399568
# 6 16 18 2006  2.3158747
```